# ¿Cómo cambiar el cursor en JavaScript para que tome la forma de una imagen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, cursor

Estoy intentando cambiar el cursor en JavaScript para que tome la forma de una imagen (en mi caso, x.png o o.png), pero no he podido hacerlo funcionar. Actualmente estoy usando la función actualizarCursor() que establece el cursor en función del contenido de las celdas. ¿Cómo puedo modificar esta función para que el cursor tome la forma de una imagen personalizada?

Código actual:

```js
function actualizarCursor() {
  cells.forEach(cell => {
    if (cell.textContent === "") {
      cell.style.cursor = `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><text x="0" y="35" font-size="40">${currentPlayer}</text></svg>') 16 16, auto`;
    } else {
      cell.style.cursor = "default";
    }
  });
}
```

Además, ¿cómo puedo asegurarme de que la imagen se muestre correctamente en diferentes navegadores y dispositivos?

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, bienvenido! ¿La idea es que el cursor cambien cuando el puntero pasa sobre determinadas celdas y dependiendo el contenido que estas tengan?

Answer (score 1):

No se cambia con JavaScript, de hecho es mucho más simple. Es puro CSS.
Sólo es usar el atributo `cursor` en CSS con un URL que lleve al recurso en sí, ya sea externo (de internet) o un PATH dentro de tu misma página, de esta manera:

```css
.xd {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/heart.svg), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="xd">Pon tu mouse aquí</div>
```

Comment: Estoy tentado a votar negativamente la pregunta. Sí se puede cambiar el cursor con CSS; pero no entiendo por qué dices que no se hace a través de Javascript; hay varios ejemplos en línea que demuestran cómo hacerlo. Tienes alguna fuente que lo desaliente? Existe algún artículo que recomiende hacerlo únicamente a través de CSS?

Comment: @Arriel No me refiero a que no se puede con JS. El OP puso en su pregunta que quería cambiar la imagen del cursor, no que quería que fuera específicamente con JS ni que quería que cambiara dinámicamente. Me parece más sencillo usar CSS sí lo único que se desea es cambiar la imagen del mismo.

Comment: Creo que la primera línea de la descripción dice que OP intentó hacerlo en javascript. Más importante aún es el título de la pregunta misma: *¿Cómo cambiar el cursor **en JavaScript** para que tome la forma de una imagen?*. No me malinterpretes, se aprecia tu entusiasmo por ayudar y tu contribución, pero esta respuesta no contesta exactamente la pregunta de OP